# Why can't I install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite?

Tags: entity-framework

I am following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio

I am immediately stopped because I can not complete the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

This is the error:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 7.0.0'. You are trying to install a package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I am attempting to learn how to use the Entity Framework and so I don't know much regarding this.  Any advice would be helpful even if it's a link to something I need to read.

Comment: ...why are you using .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: no idea?  i did not choose the version i just tried to follow the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About the tutorial

The tutorial is about **.netCore** but in the error message you can see that you created a **.netFramework** project `'.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'`.

Create a new console application, but don't select projects that have **(.NET Framework)** in the description.

[image]

### About the Sqlite package *(only if continue the practicing with .netFramework)*

The command `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` will try to install the last version. Currently, the last version is `7.0.0`. This version only work with **.NET 6.0**.

> You can check existing .net versions right [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks)

So, you need to specify the version. The version for **.NET 4.7.2** is the `3.1.31`.

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Version 3.1.31`

> Nuget Sqlite package info [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/3.1.31)

Comment: I think i get it.  one question.  I have been told that I will be working on Entity Framework as well as Linq, but I am unsure if there is a particular version that works with both of these.  I am attempting to get ahead of the situation and learn before this job actually starts.  Any suggestions?

Comment: EF 6 for .netFramework and EF Core (EF 7+) for .NET. Search Youtube tutorials for beginners, and you are good to go. Use Microsoft documentation for specifics details.

Comment: LINQ (Language Integrated Query) is a common library (System.Linq namespace) that works with both .net and .netFramework. It's commonly used with collections (System.Collections.Generic namespace) and has many extension methods that are useful when working with lists or arrays.

Comment: One more thing, as you can see in the ".net versions" link on the answer, there is a ".netStandard". You must check the compatibility first, but when a package has compatibility with DotNetStandard, that work on both DotNet and DotNetFramework.
DotNetStandard 1.6 work on everything practically. 2.0+ only works with DotNet.